# Running Mathematica from MatLab

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I need to run some mathematica commands inside matlab codes. Looking around I found there used to be two alternatives for this:

-SMATLink (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20573-smatlink-let-matlab-dance-with-mathematica)
-Mathemtica Symbolic Toolbox for MatLab (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6044-mathematica-symbolic-toolbox-for-matlab-version-2-0)

Both are old however and won't run on newer versions of MatLab. Does anybody know an alternative? MatLink only seems to interact Mathematica with MatLab by running commands in Mathematica, so it does suit not my needs...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The toolbox in the second link you provided seems to work under R2014b according to a comment. Have you tried that?

Comment: I dont know how the guy from the first comment managed to install the package. The mathematica version he claims to be using does not even use mathlink anymore (not to be confused with matlink), which contains some necessary files for the package installation...

Comment: I don't have Mathematica, so I can just try to give an educated shot in the dark: You can call console commands in MATLAB using `system`. It might be possible to create a Mathematica script and call this via the console in MATLAB. Another suggestion, though probably not a very good one: MAPLE offers direct MATLAB integration, maybe migrating something from Mathematica to MAPLE is easier.